# antlr left recursion for nesting boolean expressions

Tags: antlr, grammar, left-recursion

I am writing an antlr grammar in which I'd like to be able to have nested expressions, which can be either "simple" expressions or boolean expressions (with optional parentheses). A simple expression is just one with an lhs and rhs, such as `a = 5`

I'd like to be able to support these types of expressions:

```
a = 5
a = 5 OR b = 10
a = 5 OR (b = 10 AND c = 12)
(a = 5 AND b = 10) OR (c = 12 AND D = 13)
```

My grammar looks like:

```
STRING: CHAR+;
fragment CHAR: ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9'); 

booleanOp: 'AND' | 'OR';
simpleExpr: STRING '=' STRING;
expr: simpleExpr | parenExpr | booleanExpr;
parenExpr: '(' expr ')';
booleanExpr: expr (booleanOp expr)+;
```

I'm getting an error that `expr` and `booleanExpr` are mutually left recursive. I understand *why* that is happening, but I'm not really sure how to work around this if I want to be able to nest boolean expressions within each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the homepage of www.antlr.org you can see this sample grammar:

```
grammar Expr;
  prog: (expr NEWLINE)* ;
  expr: expr ('*'|'/') expr
  | expr ('+'|'-') expr
  | INT 
  | '(' expr ')' ;
```

A little editing and it will be what you need.  This is for ANTLR 4.  Which version are you using?  I'm sure every version of ANTLR has an expression grammar sample.

Comment: I'm using antlr3, but let me try 4 ... it seems to be more accepting

Comment: I want to know why the expr rule is not giving a 'left-recursive' error.